# How to: Dynamically move Google Gauge?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, xml

[Watch the CPU and memory gauges](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html#Loading) for a second. They move dynamically.

The example code shown below does not move the gauges like that (or at least when I tried it in my own project.)

How do I to get it moving dynamically like that?

(Also, will these gauges slow down my site connecting to Google? On the other hand, will it bring up my rankings?)

Comment: How is this related to AppEngine?

Comment: @Adam Crossland:Sorry wasn't sure.....what is the correct tag for google code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example code and the actual demo are different. Try this instead:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function Timer(){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,b){this.t[a]=[(new Date).getTime(),b]};this.tick("start")}var loadTimer=new Timer;window.jstiming={Timer:Timer,load:loadTimer};if(window.external&&window.external.pageT)window.jstiming.pt=window.external.pageT;if(window.jstiming)window.jstiming.report=function(g,d){var c="";if(window.jstiming.pt){c+="&srt="+window.jstiming.pt;delete window.jstiming.pt}if(window.external&&window.external.tran)c+="&tran="+window.external.tran;var a=g.t,h=a.start;delete a.start;var i=[],e=[];for(var b in a){if(b.indexOf("_")==0)continue;var f=a[b][1];if(f)a[f][0]&&e.push(b+"."+(a[b][0]-a[f][0]));else h&&i.push(b+"."+(a[b][0]-h[0]))}if(d)for(var j in d)c+="&"+j+"="+d[j];(new Image).src=["http://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=3","&s=gviz&action=",g.name,e.length?"&it="+e.join(",")+c:c,"&rt=",i.join(",")].join("")};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var csi_timer = new window.jstiming.Timer();
csi_timer.name = 'docs_gauge';

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  csi_timer.tick('load');

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRows(3);
  data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory');
  data.setValue(0, 1, 80);
  data.setValue(1, 0, 'CPU');
  data.setValue(1, 1, 55);
  data.setValue(2, 0, 'Network');
  data.setValue(2, 1, 68);

  csi_timer.tick('data');

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  csi_timer.tick('new');

  var options = {width: 400, height: 120, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5};
  chart.draw(data, options);

  csi_timer.tick('draw');
  window.jstiming.report(csi_timer);  

  setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 13000);
  setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 5000);
  setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 26000);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Their demo uses a pseudo random number generator to update the graph. It's a little misleading.

I draw the initial chart using their code and then use an ajax call to fetch the updated data as a json string - from php. Then I populate the data table and update the chart with jQuery/javascript. I haven't gotten around to making a full tutorial yet b/c it's not ready for production...

The hardest part is getting your data formatted correctly on the server-side and feeding ajax without blowing up the browser. The code appears to be really fast and when you're monitoring a webserver you kinda want the image rendering to be done somewhere else. It works but, at this point, it's still not completely browser agnostic - which is why I chose to use re-write in jQuery.

As far as I know, your page rankings are unrelated...

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions are using random generated number to animate the gauge for demo. What if you want to show a real value AND animate it at the same time?
Here is the solution:

[Code it yourself on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozkantarik/Lzty2y0k/)

```
  function isEven(n) {
     return n % 2 == 0;// true|false
  }
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Memory', 80],
      ['CPU', 55],
      ['Network', 68]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 120,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
// Animate Gauges: (ArrayNum(start:0), ColumnInThatArray(start:0), NewValue) 
// OR in anoher words(rowIndex, columnIndex, NewValue)

    setInterval(function() {
      var chartValue = data.getValue(0, 1);
      if (isEven(chartValue)){
      data.setValue(0, 1, (chartValue + 5));
      } else {
      data.setValue(0, 1, (chartValue - 5));
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 450);// milisecond
    setInterval(function() {
      var chartValue = data.getValue(1, 1);
      if (isEven(chartValue)){
      data.setValue(1, 1, (chartValue + 1));
      } else {
      data.setValue(1, 1, (chartValue - 1));
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 600);// milisecond
    setInterval(function() {
      var chartValue = data.getValue(2, 1);
      if (isEven(chartValue)){
      data.setValue(2, 1, (chartValue + 3));
      } else {
      data.setValue(2, 1, (chartValue - 3));
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 1000);// milisecond
  }
```