# Where does Google keep this file used for Google Visualization can I make it local to my site? Also, any examples of code to get gauges to work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-visualization

**EDIT**
Please see the produced html and Javascript here:
http://jsfiddle.net/GregMcNulty/K6Vrb/1/

According to this [Comment 4](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5#c4) - the comment at the beginning of ***the file*** is causing issues.

My question is, which file is this and when does it get loaded?

The only file I load is: https://www.google.com/jsapi as shown in the [example](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html#Example).

So if I can figure out when and how it is called, can I make this a local file on my site instead of calling it from google.... and edit it to remove the comments, so i can get the google gauges to work in IE?

Thanks.

Not sure why putting the meta data in the head is not working for me either? Should that work in all cases?

Anyone have a specific example they can show how they got the google visualization/charts working with IE?

The head without any doc type, however, it renders the rest of the body (not shown) terribly...

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />  
<title>
    Your Levels
</title>

     <!-- Google JavaScript for gauges -->
       <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript' ></script>   
    <!-- Style Sheet -->
       <link href="Styles/EliteCircle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- My local JavaScript File -->
       <script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>


<body>

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Stats.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
```

...etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy.

The DOCTYPE in the comment is the DOCTYPE in *your* web page.  The one that calls the Google Visualization javascript.

Proof:

1. Take the Gauge example on the Google Visualization page.
2. Cut and paste it in a file g.html on your desktop
3. do *not* add any DTD `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` on top of the HTML tag.
4. Open it in IE8 => works
5. add the DTD shown in 3 => broken.

So basically, to make it work, in IE8, omit the DTD before the `html` opening tag.

I've tried other DTDs, especially the xhtml 1 strict, known to make IE behave.  No luck yet.

**Update**

By the way, when I add the dtd inserted by visual studio (antique 4.01) it still works.
I've also added your header.  The file below works fine in IE8 for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<title>
    Your Levels
</title>
     <!-- Style Sheet -->
       <link href="Styles/EliteCircle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- My local JavaScript File -->
       <script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['gauge'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
            data.addRows(3);
            data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory');
            data.setValue(0, 1, 80);
            data.setValue(1, 0, 'CPU');
            data.setValue(1, 1, 55);
            data.setValue(2, 0, 'Network');
            data.setValue(2, 1, 68);

            var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            var options = { width: 400, height: 120, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
                yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5
            };
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
       <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Stats.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">  
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the doc type from my site but still no luck. I did put the example gauges in a separate file and they did work in IE, so it must be something else besides the doc type in my page....let me add my head section to the question in case anything pops out. thanks again.

Comment: Nothing wrong so far. I stuck your header on top of the google example (see updated answer) and it's still OK.

Comment: I have added the code to a JsFiddle. If you could take a quick look at it I would greatly appreciate it. If you can see what the issue is I will see how I can get you more more of my reputation, thanks.http://jsfiddle.net/GregMcNulty/K6Vrb/1/

Comment: @Greg The code looks nice and clean.  Looks like you are another victim of IE X-Browser compatibility hell.  I'll have a deeper look this morning.

Comment: @Greg I believe the problem lies only in the computation of the oldVal in the updateSL, updateCL, and updateLL functions.  I've hard coded 34 as values for oldVal inside each of these functions in jsfiddle and the gauge show up in IE.

Comment: @Greg I changed the getElementsByName by the corresponding getElementById with the id instead of names. I've updated the jsfiddle source code.  Works in FF and IE. Should work for you as well.

Comment: @Alain: Thanks! I will give it a try this evening. Thank You for taking your time, I really appreciate this. Looks like it is along the lines of this issue I had found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049221/how-do-i-make-this-getelementsbyname-work-for-ie-and-ff  Not sure I will be able to use ID as it is dynamic in ASP.NET but I think I will be able to use some jQuery method.

Comment: Looks like i can not increase the bounty on this, do you want me to open up another question for another 100 points?

Comment: Also, does this mean Google has fixed a bug somewhere?

Comment: Don't worry about the bounty Greg. It was fun to work with you.  In addition to your generous bounty, I owe you to get to know both Google Visualization for which I will no doubt find plenty of use and jsfiddle which I didn't know.  About Google, I'more enclined to think that IE is a real mess.  MS are slowly trying to make IE compliant with the W3C standards again.  So there are a lot of combinations (strict mode or quirk mode to name them) and each new version of IE has a new way of being told when to apply what mode.  Poor Google and other less wealthy JS framework author are left with it.

Comment: About the id being generated by the ASP. You could modify the ASP to put the prefix of the id in a hidden text box field. And you could do a 2 steps indirect reference.  Such as prefix = getElementById('ConfidencePrefix').innerHtml the add 'SL', 'CL' and 'LL' to that string and finally access the new confidence levels through a second wave of getElementById.

Comment: Also, If you still have difficulty with the remaining javascript, or some other fine tuning issues, please ask.  I noticed a few oddities (like the `function ttt () ;` script and left them aside because I knew I did not have the complete source code.