# How do I make this getElementsbyName work for IE (and FF)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, internet-explorer, dom

This is the JavaScript that is errored on in IE but works in FF (error - "document.getelementsbyname(...).0.innerhtml is null or not an object":

```
var oldVal = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("outSL")[0].innerHTML); //val from DB
```

This is the asp.net code where I want to grab the inner html that will be filled in by the database:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelSL" runat="server" Text="" name="outSL" style="visibility:hidden;"></asp:Label>
```

The id is dynamic, when it is rendered it looks like this, where it is the 43 I am after:

```
<span id="ctl00_cpMainContent_LabelSL" name="outSL" style="visibility:hidden;">43</span>
```

So...how can I get that 43 in IE and FF with the same function?

Thank You!

Comment: You do realize that your code says getElementById() instead of getElementByName() right?

Comment: @Nick, darn that is when I was debugging.....thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: $('span[id*="LabelSL"]').html();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have .NET 4.0 then you can write clean id's and then just use getElementById, since as Carnotaurus state's, getElementByName functions different across browsers.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

If you're stuck on .NET 2.0/3.5, then you can use jQuery to access elements by either Id, or Name, or many other selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Also I wrote a library to output a json array of ID's for .NET 2.0/3.5.

http://awesomeclientid.codeplex.com/

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2010/12/i-love-clean-client-ids-especially-with-net-2-0/

This gets around the INamingContainer slapped on all the controls runat server, it outputs an array like:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
//<![CDATA[
var controls = {
"txtUserName": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName",
"txtEmail": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail",
"btnSubmit": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"
};
//]]>
</script>
```

Then you can access the elements by ID like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById(controls.btnSubmit);
```

Answer (score 6):

GetElementByName functions differently across different browsers. I suggest you access your elements using jQuery.

Comment: what is the best method using jQuery for asp.net tag types?

Comment: I would not target elements using name or id attributes if I would help it. I would give each element a unique class and then target the element by its unique class using jQuery.

Comment: Here is a prize example: http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/CSS-Class-Names-Instead-of-ASPNET-Client-IDs.aspx

Comment: Equally, you could just the id element in .Net 4 as you are now given more control over it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx