# Referencing the ASP.NET web control in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down list in my user control, see source code below,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInd" runat="server" DataSourceID="indXmlDS" DataTextField="text" DataValueField="text"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In Page_load I have done this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
       cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "<script language='javascript' src='../Scripts/myJS.js'></script>");
        ddlInd.Attributes["onchange"] = "showTextbox()";
    }
```

So what code should I be using, if I would like to refer to this control in my external javascript file, myJS.js?

I have tried to use `document.getElementById("<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>")` but it would return **NULL**.

Can anyone help? Thanks

EDIT:

Not sure if attaching that myJS.js file would be helpful here

```
function showTextbox() {
    var sid = <%=ddlInd.ClientID %>;
    //alert(sid);
    var s = document.getElementById('<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>'); // <-- problem here 

    alert(s);
    if (s.options[s.selectedIndex].value == "Other") {
        myDiv.style.display = "inline";
        alert("display");
    }
    else {
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
        alert("none");
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

I kinda found the workaround which is to embed scripts in the user control page instead of using external script file. Thanks for the suggestions everyone. They were all very helpful.

Also the modified js script is as follows, and it works:

```
function showTextbox(objID) {
    var s = document.getElementById(objID);
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    if (s.options[s.selectedIndex].value == "Other") {
         div.style.display = "inline";
     }
     else {
         div.style.display = "none";
     }
}
```

Comment: is ddlInd.ClientID returning null or is the getElementById?

Comment: @paolo I think its document.getElementByID that returns NULL

Comment: Where and how have you tried `document.getElementById("<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>")`, as parameter for `showTextbox`? It could also be helpful to see the relevant part of your Usercontrol where `ddlInd` and the TextBox are. Doesn't `showTextbox` also needs the ID of the TextBox?

Comment: what if you comment all what you've done in page load? Still NULL is returned?

Comment: @Tim the js function showTextbox() is in the myJS.js file which is stored under Scripts folder as you can see from the code written in Page_Load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx) instead of RegisterStartupScript.

It seems in your case you're including an external javascript file, rather than javascript code that should directly appear in the page.

Also try changing the double quotes " to single quotes ' in `document.getElementById('<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>')`

**EDIT** oh, I see that you're trying to do <%=ddlIndustry.ClientID %> inside your javascript file. That is not going to be interpreted in an external js file! You should either include your function directly in teh page (not as an external file) or try to pass the ColntrolId as an argument to the js function

Comment: this seems to be a javascript error, now. Are you sure the path to your javascript file is correct? You should try "~/Scripts/myJS.js" as the path to your js file. A relative path to your js is tricky from inside a user control, because the path to the js is relative to the page where you include the control, not to the user control itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the ClientIdMode of the control to Predictable:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInd" ClientIDMode="Predictable" runat="server" DataSourceID="indXmlDS" DataTextField="text" DataValueField="text"></asp:DropDownList>
```

You can also use a static ClientId by using `ClientIDMode="Static"` in which case the ClientId will be equal to the id of the control, so you can say:

```
document.getElementById("ddlInd");
```

Comment: No luck. still giving me NULL, when I call `alert(document.getElementById("<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>"))`

Comment: @woodykiddy: and when you call: alert("<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>") ?

Comment: No luck there either when `ClientIDMode = "Static"` Not sure what's wrong with my code :(

Comment: if I do alert("<%=ddlInd.ClientID %>") it will just show a string **<%=ddlInd.ClientID%>**

Comment: @woodykiddy: Woops, you need single quotes. Which, by the way, you should probably do in your document.getElementById as well...

Answer (score 0):

you could use this to reference your control to .js file

$('select#ddlInd').val(....)

if the dropdownlist is inside a "ContentPlaceholder", you could do this

$('select#ContentPlaceholderID_ddlInd').val(...)

place it in your .js file

Note : include of course your .js file

Comment: This would assume the OP has access to jQuery, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use .NET 4.0 and are stuck on 3.5/2.0, I wrote a small library called Awesome.ClientID to solve this problem.

I've posted it before in this answer: [How do I make this getElementsbyName work for IE (and FF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049221/how-do-i-make-this-getelementsbyname-work-for-ie-and-ff/5049299#5049299)

Basically it will allow you to serialize all your controls to a JSON array, and you can change your JavaScript to:

```
document.getElementById(controls.ddlInd);
```

The library can be found here: http://awesomeclientid.codeplex.com/

Blog post about it: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2010/12/i-love-clean-client-ids-especially-with-net-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

You can use <%=Control.ClientID %> When you have script on the .aspx page if your using an External file then u have to use the control id <%=ddlInd.ClientID %> will not work.